# How to show Call Stack, Immediates, and other hidden windows in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I closed the call stack and other default windows in VS2008. How do I get them back?
I expected to find a command under the View menu, or atleast under the View\Other Windows menu. Nothing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try the Debug menu, then Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Some windows may only be available when you are in debug mode.  Try running your project and then hit the Debug->Windows menu.  You should see Call Stack, Immediate, etc.

Answer (score 6):

(File Menu)Debug > Windows

Answer (score 1):

Just use shortcut of:

Immeddiate: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>

Breakpoints: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+D,C : This key might help you to show Call Stack in Visual Studio 2019 v15.7
But I don't know why it is not working in v15.9